# How do I compile Pyparsing with Cython on WIndows?

Tags: c++, python, c, cython, pyparsing

I tried to compile Pyparsing on my Windows machine but got the following errors:

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
running build_ext
cythoning pyparsing.pyx to pyparsing.c

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
       If C{include} is set to true, the matched expression is also parsed (the
skipped text
       and matched expression are returned as a 2-element list).  The C{ignore}
       argument is used to define grammars (typically quoted strings and comment
s) that
       might contain false matches.
    """
    def __init__( self, other, include=False, ignore=None, failOn=None ):
                              ^
------------------------------------------------------------

pyparsing.pyx:2764:31: Expected an identifier, found 'include'

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
    def __init__( self, other, include=False, ignore=None, failOn=None ):
        super( SkipTo, self ).__init__( other )
        self.ignoreExpr = ignore
        self.mayReturnEmpty = True
        self.mayIndexError = False
        self.includeMatch = include
                           ^
------------------------------------------------------------

pyparsing.pyx:2769:28: Expected an identifier or literal
building 'pyparsing' extension
creating build
creating build\temp.win32-2.7
creating build\temp.win32-2.7\Release
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W
3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Python27\PC /Tcpyparsing.c /Fobuild\t
emp.win32-2.7\Release\pyparsing.obj
pyparsing.c
pyparsing.c(1) : fatal error C1189: #error :  Do not use this file, it is the re
sult of a failed Cython compilation.
error: command '"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe"' fa
iled with exit status 2
```

I did the compilation with Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Express edition and the Pyparsing module used is the most current version. Please, does anyone know of how to make this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sir, I did as you've said but there was still a compile time warning:

```
    python setup.py build_ext --inplace
    running build_ext
    cythoning pyparsing.pyx to pyparsing.c
    warning: pyparsing.pyx:413:8: Unreachable code
    building 'pyparsing' extension
    creating build
    creating build\temp.win32-2.7
    creating build\temp.win32-2.7\Release
    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W
    3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Python27\PC /Tcpyparsing.c /Fobuild\t
    emp.win32-2.7\Release\pyparsing.obj
    pyparsing.c
    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\link.exe /DLL /nologo /INCRE
    MENTAL:NO /LIBPATH:C:\Python27\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Python27\PCbuild /EXPORT:initpyp
    arsing build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\pyparsing.obj /OUT:C:\Users\iProsper\Desktop
    \pyparsing\pyparsing.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\pyparsing.lib /MAN
    IFESTFILE:build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\pyparsing.pyd.manifest
       Creating library build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\pyparsing.lib and object build\
    temp.win32-2.7\Release\pyparsing.exp
    C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin\mt.exe -nologo -manifest build
    \temp.win32-2.7\Release\pyparsing.pyd.manifest -outputresource:C:\Users\iProsper
    \Desktop\pyparsing\pyparsing.pyd;2
```

The warning is actually in the line 4: **warning: pyparsing.pyx:413:8: Unreachable code**. I then changed the line to read as:

```
    def __getattr__( self, name ):
            if True: #name not in self.__slots__:
                if name in self.__tokdict:
                    if name not in self.__accumNames:
                        return self.__tokdict[name][-1][0]
                    else:
                        return ParseResults([ v[0] for v in self.__tokdict[name] ])
                else:
                    return ""
            else:
                return None
```

and then recompiled it. One thing I noticed is that even with the warning and the edit I made, both of them compiled successfully but when when I tried to test it with the following code:

```
    from pyparsing import Word, alphas
    greet = Word(alphas) + ',' + Word(alphas) + '!'
    greeting = greet.parseString('Hello, World!')
    print greeting
```

I got the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\nwaomachux\build_pyparsing\checkout.py", line 1, in 
        from pyparsing import Word, alphas
      File "pyparsing.pyx", line 3414, in init pyparsing (pyparsing.c:100064)
    AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'ANY_VALUE'
```

I would have altered the file further and sent it to you to check it out but I'm only some few hours old with Pyparsing, so I've yet to get a grasp of the full source code.

I wouldn't know what the effect(s) of moving **withAttribute.ANY_VALUE = object()** to the beginning of **def withAttribute(*args,**attrDict):** function signify. Please, what's the fix to it? Thanks.

Comment: This will be more difficult to solve, but still not insurmountable. The problem is that in pyparsing, I used Python's ability to associate attributes with functions to define a constant value that is only relevant to one particular method by defining it as an attribute of that method. Cython apparently balks at this. The simplest fix is to change `withAttribute.ANY_VALUE` to `withAttribute_ANY_VALUE` in all places that it is used, and add `withAttribute_ANY_VALUE` to the `__all__` declaration at the top. I think that will help.

Comment: It's finally worked. The depth of your knowledge of the problem at hand is second to none. Thanks.

Comment: This post may be a bit old already but I'm seriously interested in the performance-wise outcome of the cython-compiled module. Did it have a significant impact? Thanks!

Comment: @JohannesP maybe you should read more from http://effbot.org/pyfaq/can-python-be-compiled-to-machine-code-c-or-some-other-language.htm and http://www.behnel.de/cython200910/talk.html. They would help you make informed decision on the best way to go.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect the problem is the use of 'include' as a named parameter, since `include` is a reserved C keyword. Try editing this `__init__` routine to:

```
def __init__( self, other, include_=False, ignore=None, failOn=None ):
    super( SkipTo, self ).__init__( other )
    self.ignoreExpr = ignore
    self.mayReturnEmpty = True
    self.mayIndexError = False
    self.includeMatch = include_
    self.asList = False
    if failOn is not None and isinstance(failOn, basestring):
        self.failOn = Literal(failOn)
    else:
        self.failOn = failOn
    self.errmsg = "No match found for "+_ustr(self.expr)
```

That is, just add a '_' to the parameter name, in the parameter list and in the one line that references it. This will make your Cython-compiled pyparsing slightly variant from the standard release, but I've not seen heavy use of this parameter.

Good luck, please post to the [pyparsing wiki Home page discussion](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/page/messages/home) your Cython-izing experience, and any info on how this may have sped up your pyparsing process.

Comment: I'll surely contribute to the wiki when I'm through with it. I hope to replicate it on my Ubuntu machine too. Thank you for the marvelous Pyparsing, it rocks!